# Is Golden badge required to close a question as duplicate?

Tags: support

Can I close a question as duplicate if I have 20k reps but I don't have a golden badge on any of the question related tags?

Comment: Yes, you can, but your vote will not be binding. Four other votes will be required for the question to be closed, unless a gold badge holder or a diamond moderator steps in.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a golden tag badge in one of the question's <strike>original</strike> *current* tags is required for you to be able to close it as a duplicate immediately.

More details on wielding the Mjölnir:

- [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)
- [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212)
- [It looks like the duplicate banner changed. How does it work now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268278/162704)

Comment: Current tags? Since when?

Comment: @Bergi: See the start of the accepted answer to the third linked question.

Comment: So can't someone just add a tag they do have a gold badge in to close the post,

Comment: @Halbort: nope.  Doesn't work if you were the person to add the tag.  (But two people collaborating could do it.)

Comment: Oh I did not know that. I have never actually added a tag before. I just like thinking about way to troll a system.